# CW structure for $S^2/\text{~}$ where $x \text{~} -x$ iff $x$ is on the equator

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've constructed the following CW structure for $S^2/\text{~}$ where $x \text{~} -x$ iff $x$ is on the equator, but I've been wondering whether I have attached the $2$-cells properly.

The CW structure is:

- One $0$-cell
- One $1$-cell denoted $a$
- Two $2$-cells denoted $A,B$

The 2-cell $A$ is glued along the word $a^2$, but what about the 2-cell $B$? I thought it should also be $a^2$, but after comparing to a similar solution, I'm no longer sure, since there it appears to be $a^{-2}$. I cannot seem to justify the minus though. Which is correct and how does one determine the orientation when attaching more than one $n$-cell in general? (I seem to be able to do this when it is obvious if one needs to wrap the **same cell** in different directions [e.g., once in one way and then back the other], but not when I have **different cells**).